# current_user.id returning id of the creator of an article instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using devise `current_user` to display the `edit` button depending if the `current_user` matches the `user_id` which is the one who created the `Article`.

This has never happen to me before and I've tried searching for this error but can't find anything, maybe it was a mistake I did that I haven't been able to figure out.

Anyways, here are my files:

Gems:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'

gem 'evil_icons'

gem 'devise'

gem 'ransack'

gem "will_paginate"

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

  gem 'better_errors'

  gem 'faker'

  gem 'nifty-generators'
end
```

article_controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
  # before_action :redirect_coming_soon
  # before_filter :require_permission, only: :edit

  # GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json
  def index
    @q = Article.ransack(params[:q])
    @articles = @q.result.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  end

  # GET /articles/1
  # GET /articles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /articles/new
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /articles
  # POST /articles.json
  def create
    @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update(article_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /articles/1
  # DELETE /articles/1.json
  def destroy
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to articles_url, notice: 'Article was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:name, :price, :description, :category_id)
    end

    def require_permission
      if current_user != Article.find(params[:id]).user
        redirect_to root_path
        #Or do something else here
      end
    end
end
```

Example:

Note: to enter the `better_errors` console I just put in the view I want `<%aa%>`.

I have 2 users registered

`user_id: 1, email: '1@test.com'`
`user_id: 2, email: '2@test.com'`

If I create an `Article` with user # 2 and go into the url `localhost:3000/articles/1` and type in the console `current_user` it will give me the `user_id: 2`

But if I log out of that user and log in with user # 1 and go to the same address and type in the console `current_user` it will give me the `user_id: 2` but everything else returns correctly (email, etc)

It's like it's returning the id of who created the article instead of returning the `current_user.id`

Also if I go into the view and add

```
<p><%= current_user.id %></p>
<p><%= current_user.email %></p>
```

It works normal like it should, it returns the id and email of the logged in user, but in the console it doesn't, it returns the id of the one who made the article instead.

[image]
[image]

```
<% if current_user.id = @article.user_id %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<% else %>
```

this link will always appear too in every article even though I'm using different users.

Answer (score 0):

Well, two minds think better than one (or observe in this case).

Had a typo in the view

instead of:

```
<% if current_user.id = @article.user_id %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<% else %>
```

changed to:

```
<% if current_user.id == @article.user_id %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<% else %>
```

the double `==` signs where messing things bad...